How can I can combine Feign client with reactive spring security 6
How can I can provide jwt to my Feign client using reactive spring security 6.
I am working in spring micro-services project using spring cloud gateway, EurekaClient. I want to establish inter service communication let said serviceA to serviceB with feignClient.
@FeignClient(value = "${app.serviceB.name}")
public interface ServiceBClient {
  @GetMapping(value = "/endpoint")
  Dto callEnpointInServiceB();
}

ServiceB is secured and ServiceA has needed credential.
My question is that how can I using Reactive Spring Security to provide token to my feign client.
